# I Have G3 Users Complaining About My Navigation Drawer Being Unusable

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat, drawerlayout

"unusable" as in being extremely laggy and almost can't get to all of the items because of how slow it is. I am really at a loss to what I am doing wrong with my implementation of the navigation drawer. I am using AppCompat v7's material theme, and using the viewholder pattern. The drawer consists of only images which are 600x232 and around 35kb each in size (stored locally in the app).

Here's a sample from my MainActivity

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    . . . 

    mColorIcons = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_icons);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    adapter = new MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(this, mColorIcons);
    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerList.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT); // not sure if this is required for you. 
    mDrawerList.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    mDrawerList.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
    . . .
```

And here is what MyPerformanceArrayAdaptor looks like

```
public class MyPerformanceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

 private final Activity context;
 private final String[] names;

  static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
  }

  public MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
    super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        // reuse views
        if (rowView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
          // configure view holder
          ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
          viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView
              .findViewById(R.id.image);
          rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        // fill data
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String s = names[position];
        holder.image.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(s, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
        return rowView;
  }    
}
```

I would appreciate any input on how to improve this. I am having no issues when testing on a 2013 Moto X (4.4.4), Nexus 5 (L), and Nexus 7 (L)(2013). I cannot think of what the issue could be that specifically pertains to the LG G3. There have been a few reports of it not performing well on the HTC M8 as well.

EDIT: Here is my drawer_list_item xml code

```
  <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does "unusable" mean? What does "not performing well" mean? Have you used a service like Apkudo to see what your app looks like on various devices?

Comment: "unusable" as in being extremely laggy and almost can't get to all of the items because of how slow it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the images on the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest disabling things in the above code one by one and sending test builds to one of the more helpful users to try.

Comment: My guess for the change to send would be setScrollingCacheEnabled to true. Might be that the screens are resizing the images to be much larger and holding it all in memory.